# How to test the stationarity of a sequence of symbols

Tags: hypothesis-testing, stochastic-processes

I have a sample or trajectory of a stochastic process, like a, b, c, c, d, d, d, a, b, .... I want to to use an estimation algorithm that based on Lemple-Ziv data compression to estimate the entropy rate of this sequence. This entropy rate estimator requires that the process is stationary. How can I test the stationarity of this process so that I can use that algorithm to estimate the entropy rate of this process?

I'm stuck by this problem many days and didn't find a way to do this from the internet. Most methods are about numeric time series.

One way I'm thinking is to convert the symbols to numeric numbers, covert a to 1, b to 2, c to 3, d to 4, and the sequence becomes 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, ... and then use the stationarity test which is designed for numeric time series. I'm not sure this way is reasonable or not.

The other way I saw from a paper is to convert the sequence of symbols to a numeric data sequence, like 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, ... and then use Geweke diagnosis to test if the the mean of the first 10%, 20%, 30%, 40% and 50% of the sequence significantly different from the mean of the last 50% of the sequence. If all these five tests past, then the trajectory is said stationary.

Any suggestion or comment is appreciated!

Comment: Crutchfield, J. P. and Feldman, D. P. (2003). [Regularities unseen, randomness observed: Levels of entropy convergence](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1530990). *Chaos*, 13(1):25–54.

Comment: Your question would be improved by making explicit your precise question. For example, what is the null hypothesis you are interested in testing?

Comment: I think the null hypothesis could be the stochastic process is stationary.

Comment: You should edit your question (using the "edit" link in the lower left) to make that explicit. Also: What would a nonstationary process look like with categories? In what way would memory of past values manifest? (I.e. what is the *formal* null hypothesis?)